# Cancel changes when handling the ngGridEventEndCellEdit event in ngGrid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Is there a way to cancel the edit changes and revert the data to its original content in ngGrid, like in excel when the esc key is pressed?

**[EDIT]**

Please view the plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hmVRMhuIYBrWb9hhMTCo)

This is the javascript for the grid

```
 var app = angular.module('testApp',['ngGrid']);
    app.controller('testAppCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.gridData =   [{code: "code1", name: "name1" },
                        {code: "code2", name: "name1"},
                        {code: "code3", name: "name3"}];
   $scope.gridOptions = {
   data: 'gridData',
    enableCellSelection: true,
    enableRowSelection: false,
    enableCellEdit: true,
    columnDefs: [
        {field : 'code', displayName: 'Code', enableCellEdit: true},
        {field: 'name',displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: true}]
   };
});
```

The Grid Definition

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="testApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Basic Grid</title>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="ng-grid-2.0.11.debug.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <link href="ng-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    .gridStyle {
      border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
      width: 400px;
      height: 300px
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body id="main-document-body" ng-controller="testAppCtrl">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The problem here is that even if I press 'Esc' Key on the cell the modified data is accepted by the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KJmYbO?p=preview)

This is excel-like editing, with double click to edit, and  pressing escape cancels any change.

All you need is :

```
enableCellSelection: true,
enableCellEdit: true,
```

**[EDIT]** (in response to your edit) :

You seem to be having a library-related issue. The same code with different versions works fine : see [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pb4g7Wq3ERTcvPHBmsoA?p=preview)